# android gradient with 4 params

Tags: android, layout, gradient

How can I make a gradient like this in xml

[image: gradient]

I can not do it with just these params

```
startColor=""
centerColor=""
endColor=""
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Do not pay attention to the points line

Comment: In your case, a [Nine-Patch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) is more adapted

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#555994"
        android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
        android:startColor="#555994"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners 
        android:radius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: This one uses only 3 colors... he asked for more. And, if corner radius is 0dp, then you can omit the corners at all.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to draw it through shape you have to do work with `layer-list`. You can think about it like two rectangles and every rectangle has its own gradient color.

Comment: i tryed to do this thing but can't (

Answer (score 0):

6 years too late, but the easiest way to do more complex gradients like this is via multiple overlapping shapes in a `layer-list`, as [Blackbelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501696/blackbelt) mentioned.

The basic layout is:

- Rectangle 1 is centred at 20% down vertically. It starts at your grey colour, and centres & ends as pure white. By having the centre only partially down the drawable, the first grey -> white transition is achieved.
- Rectangle 2 is centred at 80% down vertically. It starts & ends as transparent, but has grey in the centre. As it is mostly transparent, it does not interfered with Rectangle 1.

This could also be achieved by having multiple drawables overlapping each other, but this way is simple enough. Here's a screenshot of it:
[image: overlapping gradients]

And here's the actual XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:centerY="20%"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#AAAAAA" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#AAAAAA"
                android:centerY="80%"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```